# Struggling to find a suitable Latin collation set for ə, ḩ, ṟ, ẕ, ḑ, ắ and possibly others

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, collections, ssms

My database contains names of cities and their associated provinces/districts/states. A bit over 40K rows.

I am struggling to find a suitable collation set that will desensitize all non-Latin characters.
My hope is to leave the original values they are, but to make sure the database is insensitive (so that users would be able to query the database using 'English' characters alone)

I have been testing multiple collation sets and I have found that SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
leaves me with the least amount of issues (only 186 rows contain values outside the scope of this collation).

There are some characters I wasn't able to tame (all under the 'province' column). The ones I've found are: ə , ḩ , ṟ , ẕ , ḑ , ắ .

Query results suggest that the countries containing 'yet-to-be-collated' characters are:

```
country         number of values
--------        ----------------
Afghanistan     1
Azerbaijan      31
Bahrain         1
Egypt           14
Iran            15
Iraq            3
Kuwait          3
Libya           3
Qatar           1
Saudi Arabia    15
Syria           37
Vietnam         48
Yemen           14
```

I know I can use REPLACE / TRANSLATE, but I would really rather leave the values as they are and set a suitable database-level collation (worst case, I will only TRANSLATE the stubborn 186).

Any tips as to how/where to find the collation I so dearly want for Christmas? Also, I am very new to the whole thing, so I might be missing something obvious.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.10.

Comment: [UTF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#utf8)?

Comment: Check the table definition. The column should be `NVARCHAR` and not just `VARCHAR`. With `N` the type is UCS-2 (which is almost the same as UTF-16) and will support nearly all characters you might find. Without the `N` this is just *extended ASCII*. Especially with strings from various cultures you will never find a collation to cover them all.

Comment: @ Shnugo, that's exactly it, thank you! I copied it from another source and missed it. The columns' type is indeed NVARCHAR. Works perfectly now.

Comment: I would use an Unicode column. Any available encoding should work: UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-24, or UTF-32. UCS-2 is a partial encoding that works well for most cases, unless you want Chinese characters. I would stick to full Unicode encodings to sleep well at night.

Comment: @TheImpaler Not so sure about this... UCS-2 ist consistently called "unicode" in MS docs. There are hardly any characters in written language all over the world which are not covered. We get into troubles with the rather new wave of emojis, icons and tralala. Using UTF8-collations everywhere will have quite some impact on performance. I'd use UTF8-collations e.g. for a user chat but not for region names, where I assume that the OP wants to filter, sort or join on.